# list-objects-v2 with --query and --max-items

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am trying to list items of a large bucket while using pagination. I have two separate commands that work but I am having trouble merging them into one such that I can page through responses.

Command 1:

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket <my bucket> --max-items 100
```

This returns a json with keys `"Contents"` and `"NextToken"`. Unfortunately I cannot query/filter.

Command 2:

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket <my bucket> --query "<my query>"
```

This returns a json with a list of my results, which appears to return everything (as described by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39054121/how-many-objects-are-returned-by-aws-s3api-list-objects) question which says the page size is 1000 but the CLI automatically handles paging to return all results).

How can I form a command that lets me `--query` while also specifying a `--max-items` size limit, and be provided with a `NextToken`? The following command returned an empty list:

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket <my bucket> --max-items 100 --query "<my query>"
```

Comment: Could you post your query?

Comment: What are you actually wanting to accomplish as an end-result? That is, not just getting a token, but what final result are you wanting to obtain from the bucket? Do you just want a list of all objects keys? If you can describe your end-goal, we can probably help you find the best way to achieve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `NextToken` occurs once in the result set, while `Contents` is a list with multiple items.

This command will return both values:

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket my-bucket --max-items 10 --query [NextToken,Contents[].Key]
```

The output is:

```
[
    "eyJDb250aW51YXRpb25Ub2tlbiI6IG51bGwsICJib3RvX3RydW5jYXRlX2Ftb3VudCI6IDEwfQ==",
    [
        "foo1.docx",
        "foo2.jpg",
        "2019/06/02/foo3.txt",
        "2019/06/02/foo4.js",
        "2019/06/02/foo5.py",
        "2019/06/02/foo6.html",
        "foo7.pdf",
        "CreateThumbnail.zip",
        "Jbookmarks.html",
        "basepart/20191222_1114/foo9.csv"
    ]
]
```

The first part is the Token, plus a list of object keys.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when specifying `KeyCount` in place of `NextToken`. How do I add the other potential outputs besides `Contents` to a `--query`?

Comment: @ericOnline The `NextToken` value provided by the previous call must be supplied in the subsequent call. `KeyCount` (whatever that is) is not relevant.

Comment: I'm referring to the [AWS docs here](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/2.0.34/reference/s3api/list-objects-v2.html#output). There seem to be many other outputs to `--query` besides `Contents` and `NextToken` (including `KeyCount`, `CommonPrefixes`, etc.).

Comment: Oh, are you saying that you want to _output_ the value for `KeyCount`? Yes, the Output does not seem to match the documented outputs. Some of them only appear if relevant (eg `NextToken`), but I was unable to get `KeyCount` to appear. Looks like a documentation error.

Comment: Do you have a sample query? I substituted `KeyCount` for `NextToken` in your answer above and get `null` followed by a list of all keys in `Contents`. My query: `aws s3api list-objects-v2 --max-items 1000 --bucket <buck_name> --prefix parent1/parent2/ --delimiter '/' --query "[KeyCount, Contents[?LastModified>='2021-04-25 00:00:00'] | [?LastModified<='2021-04-27 00:00:00'].{ETag: ETag, Delimiter: Delimiter, Key: Key, Size:Size, LastModified:LastModified}]"`

Comment: If you take out the `--query` section, you will see the full data returned. Many of the mentioned fields are missing. I have reported it via the AWS CLI Feedback page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231677/discussion-between-ericonline-and-john-rotenstein).